# Insert a whole json Without creating different node in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a  collection named drop down and i want  to insert all  the drop down static JSON values in a single collections without creating different node

for  eg this is my json 
  "education": [
            "Master",
            "Bachelor"
        ],
        "diet": [
            "Veg",
            "Non Veg"
        ]

Later on  if i need  to add more drop down  values i don't have to alter  the mongoose schema ,i could directly insert  the  json list
Is it possible or not? Sorry  i am  new  to  the Mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Finally an idea strike on my mind and got  the appropriate answer of my own question and like to share here. What i did is , I create  the Schema as

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const dropDownSchema = new mongoose.Schema({dropDown : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed})
 module.exports.DropDownList =mongoose.model("DropDownList",dropDownSchema);
```

later on while passing   data from the client

```
{
    "dropDown":
    {
    "education": [
        "Master"       
        ,"Bachelor"
                ],
     "diet": [
            "Veg"
            ,"Non Veg"
            ]

    }

}
```

While inserting  data i first delete all data and insert  the  fresh one  from the API

Answer (score 0):

First find the document in that collection. Assume that we are requesting with the document `_id` and we are using mongoose model named Dropdown.
Example:

```
const document = await Dropdown.findOne({_id});

//Once you have found the document 
// Add or change the existing fields
document[new_value_name] = new_values.map(val => val);

await document.save();
```

Comment: can you please explain how to create  the appropriate  mongoose schema for this type of collection, to insert different node in a single field

Comment: ```const DropdownSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 dropdown_name: String,
dropdown_items: [
{name: String}
]
})```

This will be the model for a single DropDown, to insert new values create an API with the code in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it in array of object in mongodb then you can also create a schema with Array of dropdowns

```
var DropdownSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dropdowns:[{
    dropdown_key: { type: String },
    dropdown_values: [{type: String}]
  }]});
```

While inserting data you will need to loop through Object.keys of your json list and insert into as array . You can add number of dropdown as it is stored as array of object. 
Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: is it possible  to create a mongoose schema such  that  while inserting  data we don't need  to do any code on server side and accept any JSON values  like

{
    "education": [
        "Master"       
        ,"Bachelor"
    ],
    "diet": [
         "Veg"
         ,"Non Veg"
    ],
  
   
    "motherTongue": [
       "Nepali"
       ,"Hindi"
       ,"Other"
       
    ]}

later on when we add extra  drop down values it will accept  the json values without doing any changes